# Biztalk Orchestration reverse engineer

Tags: biztalk, reverse-engineering, reflector, biztalk-orchestrations

My situation is:

- Old developer left without the code so I can not add any enhancement or fix the bug.

Do we have any service/tool that I can reverse the Orchestration (+ Mapping) to original format (from DLL/MSI, or Running BizTalk application)?

If the reverse won't work I would like to see the Orchestration flow like the Visual studio designer. That's is good enough for me to trace everything

Comment: I now can view the orchestration flow by the debugger (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577988.aspx)

Comment: Wow, nice colleague. Do you have a name so we know who not to hire? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several options

1. Use a de-compiler (such as [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/debugging)).  You can then extract a string that is the contents of the ODX file as well as the XSLT for any maps.  (I copied the string called odXML for the Orchestration out of reflector and pasted it into an empty Orchestration and re-created it.  Note you have to replace \n with a CR LF).
2. Use [BizTalk documenter](https://github.com/mbrimble/biztalkdocumenter) to document it, that will give you the Orchestration flow and various other useful information.

I have used both tools to re-create lost source code successfully for three different clients.

(Disclosure: I'm a developer for BizTalk Documenter)

Comment: great help, thank you, especially the Biztalk Documenter :) I'm just active again from Biztalk 2006R2 and the world changed

Comment: Your welcome.  I'm now actually a developer on BizTalk Documenter 2010 and am working on fixes and improvements, some of which will make it even easier to reverse engineer Orchestrations.